# specific combination of keys doesnt work on laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have my issue with my laptop (but not desktop) playing a game:
C S and D cannot be registered all at once.
im playing a game with planes, where C is too look around, S to pull the nose of the vehicle, and D to roll right. I have to be able to preform these 3 things at once, but my laptop keyboard wont let me.
if I hold C, it will only register whichever key I press first, S or D.
while C S and A (roll left) has no problem.

any idea how to fix this?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.